# Why is it allowed to call `remove_proxy` on a pure proxy?

Tags: proxy, pallet-proxy

Using `pallet-proxy`, you can execute the following sequence of calls:

- Create a new pure proxy account using `anonymous`. Let's say this reserves 10 DEV on your main account.
- (Optional) Call some function which reserves 15 DEV on the newly created anonymous account.
- Call `remove_proxy` from the anonymous account.

The result is: You lose control over the anonymous account (obviously), but the funds that you reserved for creating the account remain reserved because instead of being unreserved on *your* account, they are unreserved on the anonymous account, leaving the anonymous account with 10 free and 5 reserved DEV, which might confuse whoever reserved those 15 DEV in step 2.

Judging by [this comment](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/37cca710eed3dadd4ed5364c7686608f5175cce1/frame/proxy/src/lib.rs#L270-L271), this is (sort-of) intended behavior. Why?

Sure, you can probably burn money in more creative ways, but why doesn't `pallet-proxy` manage anonymous accounts and conventional proxies separately to prevent this strange interaction?

Comment: If you remove the pure proxy by calling `kill_anonymous` instead of `remove_proxy`, then the funds are unreserved for the spawner account, as expected. I believe that `remove_proxy` was not really meant to be used with pure proxies.

Comment: That was my impression, as well, hence this question. I would have already raised an issue if it wasn't for the comment linked in the question above that shows that the developers were aware of this interaction and apparently decided to leave it in.